# How to use a domain name in IIS?

Tags: iis, windows-server-2016

I'm trying to learn how to setup a public website with IIS, using ssl and a domain name I have purchased but I can't find any useful information online. (google only shows tutorials for how to fake it from the hosts file) Could someone please point me in the right direction?

Apologies for my question not being very specific but I'm unsure where to begin.

Extra info:
OS: Windows Server 2016 (x64)

Comment: That's because none of the rest is IIS related. You need the browser to generate the proper HTTP requests (Host name matches your domain) and the network routes the requests to your IIS server. You cannot find tutorials, because such setup depends on the browser type, and also how you plan to configure DNS. Any computer network book should get you started with the necessary background.

Answer (score 0):

Where did you purchased domain?
You only need configure your external firewall to allow external access for your port number and  map your purchased public domain to your server's public domain in your domain provider's portal website. Your domain provider should have document about how to register public domain for your IIS server.

On IIS side, you need to create a binding host header for your public domain and public IP address or unassigned IP.